# Implement the Fixed function Pipeline efficent in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, matrix, matrix-multiplication, opengl-es-2.0

I want to use fixed function methods like glTranslate(), glRotate(), glScale() in my openGL 2.0 App. I know, that I need to implement an matrix class - and have done this. My question now is about efficiency. To be able to use something like:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glScalef(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
```

I think, I need to do at least 3 matrix multiplications (assuming we have a projection and a modelview matrizes and this is for the modelview).
First would be: Identity-Matrix*Rotation-Matrix - Second is: ActualMatrix*ScaleMatrix and the last would be: projectionMatrix*ActualMatrix (and this Im passing as uniform value to my shader).

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, matrix->getProjectionModelviewMatrix());
```

So my Vertexshader looks like:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
    colorVarying = color;
}
```

Is it done the same way in OpenGL ES 1.1? It seems like, I need one matrix multiplication vor every: glRotate, glScale, glTranslate... Call - that seems very much for me. Or is there a better way? (maybe with less matrix multiplications?)

Any help on this topic would be highly appreciated! Thank you for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identity, translation, rotation, and scaling matrices don’t require a full matrix multiplication to apply, because many of the terms are always 0.0 or 1.0. If you write out the element-by-element results of multiplying other matrices by these matrices, you’ll see that many elements may only have a few terms contributing to their final values. Two simple examples:

- Given the identity matrix *I* and an arbitrary matrix *M*, *I* × *M* = *M* × *I* = *M*.
- The only non-zero elements in a scaling matrix *S* are the four along the diagonal, which we’ll call *S<sub>0</sub>*, *S<sub>1</sub>*, *S<sub>2</sub>*, and *S<sub>3</sub>*. (*S<sub>3</sub>* is always 1.0 for something like `glScalef`.) *S* × *M* scales the *n*<sup>th</sup> row of *M* by *S<sub>n</sub>*. *M* × *S* works column-by-column instead. You can also think of the identity matrix as a particularly boring scaling matrix.

The resulting element-by-element expressions for translations and rotations are a bit more complicated than these examples, but still greatly simpler than a full matrix multiplication. (Rotations also get a great deal simpler if the axis of rotation is exactly aligned with the X, Y, or Z axis.) You’ll probably want to look into modifying matrices directly when asked to translate, scale, or rotate, rather than constructing another matrix and multiplying.

Comment: Could you give me some instructions about how to implement gluLookAt without matrix multiply.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://glm.g-truc.net/about.html