# Replicate sequence of GL matrix ops manually

Tags: opengl-es, linear-algebra

I am porting a toy GL ES 1.1 codebase to GL ES 2.0. There are no built-in modelview matrix operations, so I'm attempting a drop in replacement of the `glScalef`, `glTranslatef`, `glRotatef` calls with operations on a 4x4 "current matrix".

However, my matrix math is a little sketchy, and something's going on with the multiplication ordering and row vs column major notation, etc, and I'd love it if someone could quickly outline the semantics I should be dropping in here.

For instance, assuming I start with an identity matrix, and then (in ES 1.1 code) execute in order:

```
glTranslate(A);
glRotate(B);
glTranslate(C);
```

... what math do I need to be doing on my "current matrix" to replicate this functionality in the final modelview matrix I send to a shader? I've tried keeping a matrix, and for each operation, making a new matrix that represents it, and multiplying it into the current one. The result isn't correct though, and I think there's something I don't get about pre/post-multiply, -major, etc.

Anyone willing to say a few words on the theory here? Thanks. (I'd like to understand the basics before making it super-efficient.)

(This: [Implement the Fixed function Pipeline efficent in OpenGL ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875258/implement-the-fixed-function-pipeline-efficent-in-opengl-es-2-0)
asks a similar question, but the answer talks about how to make it more efficient, and doesn't really enlighten me on the math equivalency.)

Comment: Just find OpenGL spec. There are all matrix formulae for each operation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're looking for a replacement of the opengl matrix stack to do your transformations.

Assuming you are using c/c++, I suggest having a look at the GLM library : http://glm.g-truc.net/

It's a header-only library, easy to use and the perfect replacement for the pre-opengl es 2.0 matrix stack. It even provides functionality for deprecated glu functions like gluOrtho() and gluPerspective(). Glm's matrices can easily be passed to your shader as they are conceived with shaders in mind.

You will have to make a few changes to your code; for instance converting your own vertex / matrix definitions to glm::vec3 / glm::mat4.

Here's an example of how I construct my mvp matrix that I pass to the vertex shader: in this case the actorInstance class has a few attributes like position (in the world) and rotation defined as glm::vec3's. The constructed model, model/view and model/view/projection matrices are all a property of the class:

```
void CActorInstance::update(glm::mat4 viewMatrix, glm::mat4 projectionMatrix)
{

    // act according to class behavior
    this->actorClass->act(&input, &world, &direction, &rotation);

    // calculate the translation matrix
    glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4();
    translate = glm::translate( glm::mat4(), world);

    // calculate the rotation matrix   
    glm::mat4 rotateX = glm::rotate( glm::mat4(1.0f), rotation.x, glm::vec3(1,0,0));
    glm::mat4 rotateY = glm::rotate( glm::mat4(1.0f), rotation.y, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
    glm::mat4 rotateZ = glm::rotate( glm::mat4(1.0f), rotation.z, glm::vec3(0,0,1));
    glm::mat4 rotate = rotateX * rotateY * rotateZ;

    // calculate the model matrix
    mMatrix = translate * rotate;

    // calculate the model/view matrix
    mvMatrix = viewMatrix * mMatrix;

    // calculate the model/view/projection matrix
    mvpMatrix = projectionMatrix * mvMatrix;
};
```

Obviously the mvp matrix for each object gets updated every frame according to the object's position and rotation. The viewMatrix and projectionMatrix are passed down from my camera class.
That matrix is then used to render a mesh:

```
    void CMesh::renderMesh(GLuint program, glm::mat4 *mvp)
    {
        glUseProgram(program);

        int mvpLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvpMatrix");
        int texLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "baseMap");
        glUniformMatrix4fv( mvpLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(*mvp));

// rendering code ommitted


    };
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT** : suggestions for implementing a matrix stack

```
stl::stack<glm::mat4> matrixStack; // the matrix stack
matrixStack.push_back(glm::mat4()); // push an identity matrix on the stack
```

And that is your glLoadIdentity()...

Comment: Thanks Erik. The implication here is that you're batching up you're batching up all your translation, scale, and rotation changes, and doing them all as one matrix build before rendering. I'm trying to figure out the behavior if I do them one at a time into the "current matrix". If my question isn't sensible, then help nudge me towards understanding? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "batching up"? Even with the pre-opengles 2 matrix stack you'd have to call glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() at some point if you want to transform more than one object. Personally, I don't see why you would want to replicate the previous stack behavior... it's so difficult keeping track of how your current matrix looks. That being said, there's nothing stopping you from using stacked matrices with glm.

Comment: Thanks for the further insight and update. What I'm really asking is, if my operations are: translate, rotate, translate, in order, this does some sequence of operations that is different than pre-knowing all of my rotations and translations in advance. It's not keeping a stack that's hard, it's understanding what I do to get the translate, then rotate, then translate behavior from my multiplications. Does that help at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but there's no difference; simply right-multiply the matrices (as Christian mentions in his answer) and the result should be correct. Only, I would do it in 2 steps : M' = t1M x rM; M'' = t2M x M';

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the notation you're using (I don't know what the t1-, t2- and r- prefixes mean) and why you would do this in two steps?

Comment: t1M = your first translation matrix, rM = rotation Matrix and t2M = second translation matrix. I suggest doing it in 2 steps because that way we don't mess up the order of multiplication. Oh, and here's a good article on opengl matrices : http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried keeping a matrix, and for each operation, making a new
>   matrix that represents it, and multiplying it into the current one.

Well, that's exactly how it's done. Nothing fancy to it.

The respective matrices for calls to [`glRotate`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml), [`glTranslate`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glScale`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScale.xml) (and also [`glOrtho`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), [`glFrustum`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrustum.xml), [`gluLookAt`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) and [`gluPerspective`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml), of course) are rather easy to construct, as seen in the links.

You just have to right-multiply the respective transformation matrix `T` on the current matrix `M`:

```
M' = M * T
```

because we (or the old OpenGL you want to replicate) want the last transformation called before drawing to be applied on the object first.

Then you also have to be consistent with the storage of your matrix (row-major vs column-major), no matter for which you settle. But since you're using OpenGL, column-major storage would be a good idea, since it let's you upload them easier to GLSL (nothing against the transpose-flag, though), works better with vectorized SIMD-instructions (like x86's SSE) and moreover works better with other libraries designed for OpenGL (which use column-major matrices for the same reasons). You only have to be consistent with the storage and don't mix it up in different function calls.